# Apple Mach-O Linker (id) Error - Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) C++ SFML

Tags: c++, linker, sfml

OK so I tried checking the other solutions first ,but none of them worked and Yea... There is two errors ,even though I followed the code straight from the documentation. I think it may be a problem with the files ,but I don't think it would ,since the files are all .hpp unless if they are bad.I am a novice so this might be something stupid that I missed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
int main()
{
    // create the window
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My window");

    // run the program as long as the window is open
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        // check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration of the loop
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            // "close requested" event: we close the window
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        // clear the window with black color
        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

        // draw everything here...
        // window.draw(...);

        // end the current frame
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The syntax is error free and it has to be a library error of some sort.

UPDATE FOUND OUT THE ANSWER. Still answering and asking question to help other in case they run into the same problem I did ,since all the solutions from stack overflow weren't really solutions to this specific problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so the problem isn't inside your syntax since it is perfectly fine. The problem was that You probably forgot to add the system file for sfml ,which is the reason why it's not working. Add all the libraries that you need including the system one for sfml. 
The file should look like

```
libsfml-system.2.4.2.dylib
```

you need that or it won't work. Make sure you added that and the other files you need then it should work (it did. This is the OP BTW. ).